# Display all products in my homepage - magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to build one template from the begining. I have all things already prepared, and now I have a homepage in where i want to display all products available in a grid. So i have rendered list.phtml from the layout.
list.phtml :

```
<?php
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();

$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">

<?php // Grid Mode ?>

<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid">
    <?php endif ?>

            <li>
                productsample
            </li>


    <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

this shows the number of products times, the word productsample, so i think i am loading good all the product, but my problem is that i dont know how to display them (photo,link,addtocart,price,name...)
thanks to all

Comment: So, just check `app/design/frontend/base/default/catalog/product/list.phtml` file

Comment: it was the first thing i did, but it doesnt works....it shows that there are no products in this section, because i am in homepage and the file you told me show products of the active category

Comment: yes i know. But you can copy-paste the code inside `foreach`, where all product's data is outputed. Anyway use `getData()` method on `$_product` and you will be able to output almost all the product data

Comment: first of all thanks a lot for your help ;) . i will answer myself to show you 2 things

Comment: If you just want to display all products from a category (or by linking all products to that category) you can also adjust the URL that is loaded as the homepage. Check `System > Configuration > Web > Default Web URL` and fill the field with `catalog/category/view/id/<your_category_id_with_all_products>`.

I'm not saying this is your solution, but just so you know the existence of this feature. It might come in handy. This way most of the data including pagination etc. is already in place. 

If you want more customization you probably do need to build something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

when i use getdata i obtain this:

array(11) { ["entity_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["entity_type_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["attribute_set_id"]=> string(2) "10" ["type_id"]=> string(6) "simple" ["sku"]=> string(10) "1343918767" ["has_options"]=> string(1) "0" ["required_options"]=> string(1) "0" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2012-08-02 14:46:29" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2012-08-02 17:09:43" ["is_salable"]=> string(1) "1" ["stock_item"]=> object(Varien_Object)#336 (5) { ["_data":protected]=> array(1) { ["is_in_stock"]=> string(1) "1" } ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=> bool(false) ["_origData":protected]=> NULL ["_idFieldName":protected]=> NULL ["_isDeleted":protected]=> bool(false) } }

i need name, price...

i have sustituted this: $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
in exchange of this: $_productCollection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

because if i use the first it shows me that there are no products in the actual category.

then i have sustitute inside the foreach the code inside the foreach in default list.phtm, but it doesńt shows me the products. there is some kind of error in product img because it stops in the first product, in its image. here is the code:

code:

```
<?php
//     $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_productCollection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">

<?php // Grid Mode ?>

<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid">
    <?php endif ?>

        <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" /></a>
            <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
            <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
            <div class="actions">
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>


    <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

first < a > inside < li >, its img isnt working

Answer (score 0):

if you use cms home page then just put this code `{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="your cat id" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}` assign all product to this category.
Or you can use list.phtml file code directly to list all product just put below code.

```
  $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)->load();
```

just put this code instead of this `$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();`